# How to specify default function parameter which is a function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, closures

I was wondering how can one specify default value of a parameter, which is supposed to be a function? I attempted doing it via following function closure:

```
function foo($func = function(){}) {
    $func();
}

function bar() {
    $this->foo(); // Default parameter is supposed to be here

    $this->foo(function(){
        echo("non default func param");
    });
}
```

Which results in syntax error with message

> "expression is not allowed as a parameter default value".

Comment: why not: call function inside foo() function..and just return the result in `function()`

Comment: share actual code example in your question

Comment: @devpro, I have a hard time understanding your response and would appreciate any code snippets. As to actual example, snippet in my OP is my actual example.

Comment: Couldn't you affect a `null` default value, then check its affectation? Like `function foo ($fn = null) { if (is_callable($fn) { $fn(); } else { /* default process here */ } }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196048/discussion-between-arslancharyev31-and-treybake).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to go about it is to set the default parameter to `null`, then check if the parameter was in fact null - if it was, define a "default" function to be used instead.

Then check if the parameter is callable or not - if it is not callable, raise an exception - otherwise, call the function!

```php
function foo($func = null) {
    // If $func is null, use default function
    if ($func === null) {
        $func = function() {
            echo "Default!\n";
        };
    }
    // Verify that whatever parameter was supplied is a valid closure
    if (!is_callable($func)) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid parameter supplied');
    }
    // Call the function!
    $func();
}

function bar() {
    foo(); // Default parameter is supposed to be here

    foo(function(){
        echo "Non default func param \n";
    });
}

bar();
```

Output of the above would be

> Default!
>   Non default func param

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/ZTpn3

Comment: I had the same idea. One question, why didn't you use `is_callable()` to check if that `$func` is a function? Does your approach have more advantages or whatever?

Comment: It is a nice workaround. Thank you. Sad that PHP doesn't have built in functionality to provide default function arguments for higher order functions.

Comment: It would probably work just as well, I have no specific reason for why I did not use `is_callable()` - that's probably better in terms of readability at least!

Comment: Personally, I would actually prefer the above method, rather than specifying a default parameter as an anonymous function - I find this approach cleaner, but that's personal preferences :-)

Comment: @Qirel, interesting opinion. I though the whole point of default parameters was to eliminate explicit comparison of parameters to `null` which can be considered boilerplate

Comment: @Qirel - Oh, nice to know there is any difference! If the version of PHP is recent enough, I think you could write `foo(?Closure $func = null)` instead of verifying if the parameter is valid closure.

Comment: @arslancharyev31 For single values, like arrays, integers and strings - sure! But to define a function as a default parameter could easily become messy (unless its a specific function, like `$func = func()`).

Comment: @KévinBibollet Type-hinting, or type-declarations, was introduced in PHP5, as [per the docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration). But throwing an exception can be caught, an incorrect type given will give a fatal error which you can't recover from.